# Git: How to continue Git fetch after an unexpected abort?

Tags: git, git-fetch

The code in server side is very big about 20GB.
So it will takes a long time to download. I tried several times after download more than 10GB, server abort unexpected.
My operation like this:

```
git fetch --depth=100 url
//about 5GB is downloaded
git fetch --unshallow
// download about 10GB more ,the remote hung up unexpectedly
```

Can I continue to download?  If I can't , the 10GB is useless, how can delete them?

Comment: Consider [using git-lfs to slim down your repository](https://www.atlassian.com/git/tutorials/git-lfs). It will avoid many problems.

Comment: Try running `git fsck`. If it doesn't find any broken file, my guess is that you can safely run `git fetch --unshallow` again, and it should effectively start from the point where previous try ended - it shouldn't download already present objects again. You can run `git gc` afterwards, if the repo seems too big. However, I haven't done that and my understanding of git internals is rather limited, so I may be wrong. Anyway, running `git gc` will ensure you won't reuse the already downloded part.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If a fetch aborted, it will not write any changes to your filesystem. This is because your local repository would not be in a stable state if it wrote them to your computer.

There is no way to resume a fetch/pull/clone, so your only choice is to fetch again.

To cleanup unnecessary files use `git gc`

https://git-scm.com/docs/git-gc

Comment: I think you answered my question--can't resume. But I found ".git" folder increase by 10GB(after I use  "git fetch --unshallow" and aborted), before it was 5GB.  It means there are some redundant data,right? how can I delete them?

Comment: edited answer .. git gc seems to be what you are after

Comment: *"If a fetch aborted, it will not write any changes to your filesystem."*  
That's not correct, it leaves `<gitdir>/objects/pack/tmp_pack_*` files in this case. Furthermore the approach with `git gc` works only if the tmp files are older than `gc.pruneExpire` (default to two weeks). `--prune=now` is a bad idea, see my answer for the ratoinale.

Answer (score 2):

You can't resume an aborted fetch/clone easily, but you may unpack the already received objects manually:

```
for pack in $(git rev-parse --git-dir)/objects/pack/tmp_pack*; do
    cat "$pack" |
    git unpack-objects
done
```

Since you are using a shallow clone in the first place, you could also use e.g. `git fetch --deepen=100` in a loop until everything has been downloaded to reduce the impact of an aborted fetch.
The option `--deepen=<N>` seems to be supported [since `v2.11` (end of 2016)](https://github.com/git/git/commit/cccf74e2da85808478c784e403a69bbfe2b9f518).

To get rid of the 10 GB extra data just run `git prune`. This is the fastest and safest method. You may also delete the `<gitdir>/objects/pack/tmp_pack_*` files manually.
In principle `git gc` works as well, but it deletes left over files older than `gc.pruneExpire` (defaults to two weeks) only. Using the option `--prune=now` is dangerous, since it deletes all other dangling objects as well. I am not sure if this also touches the reflog, there seems to be an dedicated option for that. But anyway, I suggest to not use `--prune=now` in this case. Furthmore it takes much longer (because it does other housekeeping stuff as well).

Answer (score 0):

Give a try to:

```
$ git gc
```

From the man:

```
NAME
       git-gc - Cleanup unnecessary files and optimize the local repository
```